# Java - How to double only Vowels

Tags: java

I am trying to write code that would double all vowels within a string.  So if the string is hello, it would return heelloo.
This is what I currently have:

```
public String doubleVowel(String str)
{
    for(int i = 0; i <= str.length() - 1; i++)
    {
        char vowel = str.charAt(i);
        if(vowel == 'a' || vowel == 'e' || vowel == 'i' || vowel == 'o' || vowel == 'u')
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since `String` is immutable, you'll have to have some kind of temporary structure where you build the output. `StringBuilder` was created for this very purpose.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a *regular expression* with a single call to [`String.replaceAll(String, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) and your method might be `static` because you don't need any instance state (also, don't forget upper case vowels). Something like

```
public static String doubleVowel(String str) {
    return str.replaceAll("([AaEeIiOoUu])", "$1$1");
}
```

Where `$1` matches the first (only) pattern grouping expressed in `()`.

Comment: I think you should add a little bit about `$1$1`

Comment: Good thing everyone loves regular expressions

Comment: Or you could just use `(?i)[aeiou])`. Anywhich-way, a really good answer :)

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a temporary extra string(builder) and add vowels twice to that local variable, then return it:

```
public String doubleVowel(String str)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i <= str.length() - 1; i++)
    {
        char vowel = str.charAt(i);
        if(vowel == 'a' || vowel == 'e' || vowel == 'i' || vowel == 'o' || vowel == 'u')
        {
           sb.append(vowel); // add it to the string
        }
        sb.append(vowel); // add any character always, vowels have been added already, resulting in double vowels
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, but you shouldn't name the variable `vowel`, since it's only a vowel when the `if` statement is true. Just name it `c` or `ch`.

Answer (score 4):

Let me also add to these good answers a solution that doesn't involve regex or `StringBuilders` / long `or` comparison, so that you can choose the one that best suits your needs.

```
public String doubleVowel(String str)
{
    String vow = "aeiou";

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {

                if (vow.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) != -1) {

                    str = str.substring(0, i + 1) + str.substring(i++, str.length());
                }

    }

   return str;
}
```

Comment: Be aware, that although functionally correct, this is *very* inefficient, performance-wise. --- Also, it can be slightly improved by removing the `charAt()` call from the concatenation and changing `++i` to `i++`.

Comment: True that, thanks I did this very quickly and didn't notice. Fixed.